# How is an if statement possible with decision variables in CPLEX

Tags: mathematical-optimization, modeling, linear-programming, cplex, opl

How can I formulate my model that it undertakes a maintenance at 450 and a cleaning at 150?

```
forall(w in W, t in T, s in S, p in P, m in M)  
   (450<=hub[m][w][t][s])<=(b_maint[w][m][t][s]==1);

forall(w in W, t in T, s in S, p in P, m in M)  
   (hub[m][w][t][s]>=150)<=(b_clean[w][m][t][s]==1);
```

I also want that after my maintenance the hub is set back to 0
(hub is my production quantity) Is this formulation right?.

```
forall(w in W, t in T, s in S, p in P, m in M)  
   (b_maint[w][m][t][s]==1)==(hub[m][w][t][s]==0);
```

And can i also model bounds like this:

```
forall(w in W, t in T, s in S)  
   (135<=sum(p in P, m in M)r_x[m][w][p][t][s] && sum(p in P, m in M)r_x[m][w][p][t][s]<=185)==(b_clean[w][t][s]==1);
```

I tried it also already like this:

```
(135<=sum(p in P, m in M)r_x[m][w][p][t][s] <=185)==(b_clean[w][t][s]==1);
```

but that doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

You may use logical constraints:

```
(x==1) => (y<=2);
```

This means if (x==1) then y will be less than 2.

You may also use equivalence:

```
(x==3) == (z>=3)
```

Comment: Is that not how i did it? If the production (hub) is >= 450, the maintenance has to be carried out (binary b_maint==1)? Or did i make a mistake?

Answer (score -1):

you wrote

```
forall(w in W, t in T, s in S, p in P, m in M)    
   (450<=hub[m][w][t][s])<=(b_maint[w][m][t][s]==1);
```

which you could have written

```
forall(w in W, t in T, s in S, p in P, m in M)    
   (450<=hub[m][w][t][s])=>(b_maint[w][m][t][s]==1);
```

=> means **IMPLY**

Is that what you meant ? Maybe what you meant is the inverse constraint:

```
forall(w in W, t in T, s in S, p in P, m in M)    
       (b_maint[w][m][t][s]==1)=>(450<=hub[m][w][t][s]);
```

Comment: Do you know maybe also how to model the bounds correctly?